# Selenium - Button is clickable First time and second time throws exception

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests

I am running UI ATPs. In that I have different buttons, when try to click on button first time - it is clickable. But Second time when I try to click if same button also it gives me exception:
This is really unexpected behavior at my end. Because, Same tests are running on other people's machine. I cross checked Selenium ,chromedriver ,Chrome versions. All are same. 
Chrome : Version 64.0.3282.140 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Chrome driver: 2.35.0
Selenium : 1.0.19.0

Code for ButtonClick:

```
public static void SafeClick(this IWebElement element, int intervalInSeconds = 1, int timeoutInSeconds = 30)
        {
            bool success = false;
            int counter = 0;
            while (!success && counter < timeoutInSeconds)
            {
                try
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(intervalInSeconds));
                    element.Click();
                    success = true;
                    return;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    counter += intervalInSeconds;
                }
            }

            Assert.Fail(element.ToString() + " was unable to be clicked.");
        }
```

Comment: Does the button grey-out after click? Is the button maybe unclickable for 1 second after a click? If you manually spam-click the button, what is the behaviour?

Comment: Can you click twice manually? And What is the exception are you getting?

Comment: Button is not grey out. Manually if I click - test is passing.

Comment: Exception which I am getting is : unknown error: Element <button type="button" name="abc" id="abc" title="Expand for more options" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-dropdown-menu" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-disabled="Permission">...</button> is not clickable at point (511, 191). Other element would receive the click: <div class="dropdown-backdrop"></div>
  (Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.140)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)

Comment: after `element.Click();`  add `Thread.sleep(500);`

Comment: at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Click()
   at ProjectSharePSPluginTestsShared.IWebElement_Extensions.SafeClick(IWebElement element, Int32 intervalInSeconds, Int32 timeoutInSeconds)

Comment: @Senior Pomidor Added, but didn't helped

Comment: @Shraddha what is the exception raised by `element.Click();`?

Comment: I have added exception in above comments